# What is my current storage account and file share?

Tags: azure, fileshare, azure-storage-account

How do I figure out what storage account and file share is currently being used by my cloud shell? Get-AzStorageAccount just gives a list of all the storage accounts...

Answer (score 4):

You could run the `df` command on the Cloud Shell to discover which file share is mounted as **clouddrive**. For example, there is a file share path `//storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/filesharename`

[image]

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#how-cloud-shell-storage-works

Comment: Interesting...I can see similar output, but not the filesharepath that you are seeing. But it's a start. I would have thought there would be a parameter on Get-AzStorageAccount or Get-AzFileShare, that would tell me my current session's storage account/fileshare...

Comment: In the output, do you see the format `//storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/filesharename`? Then you can search the storage account name in the search bar, you will find the specific resource group name like cloud-shell-storage-region.  You can get the storage context as `Get-AzStorageAccount -name storageaccountname -resourceGroupName cloud-shell-storage-region`.

Comment: I suggest reading the linking article about how the Azure cloud shell storage works. The `Get-CloudDrive` cmdlet retrieves the Azure file share information currently mounted by the `clouddrive` in the Cloud Shell.

Comment: Any more questions? If my reply is helpful, please accept it.